# Examples of Web Crypto API on IE11

Tags: cryptoapi

I am trying to import RSA and AES-GCM keys in *jwk* format using Web Crypto API on Internet Explorer 11. Can anyone give me examples of how to do it?

The reason why I am asking is according to this msdn [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302332(v=vs.85).aspx), the *keyData* parameter must be an ArrayBufferView. However, if the *format* parameter is *jwk*, the function should accept a Dictionary containing the key in jwk format, which is how Chrome and Firefox work. I have no idea about how to convert a Dictionary to an ArrayBufferView.

The examples I found [here](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples) do not work for IE.

Comment: you should not need to convert it. the docs are just not that great and that page also claims jwk among the "_supported formats for both importKey and exportKey_". as a webdev, my [educated hunch](http://caniuse.com/cryptography/embed) is that jwk simply won't work with IE11 (it should on edge).